# Flask - Get list of routes without "@login_required" routes

Tags: python, flask

I found this useful function on [pythonprogramming.net](https://github.com/PythonProgramming/PythonProgramming.net-Website) to create a `sitemap.xml` based on all routes defined:

```
@app.route('/sitemap.xml', methods=['GET'])
def sitemap():
    try:
      """Generate sitemap.xml. Makes a list of urls and date modified."""
      pages=[]
      ten_days_ago=(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)).date().isoformat()
      # static pages
      for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
          if "GET" in rule.methods and len(rule.arguments)==0:
              pages.append(
                           ["http://pythonprogramming.net"+str(rule.rule),ten_days_ago]
                           )

      sitemap_xml = render_template('sitemap_template.xml', pages=pages)
      response= make_response(sitemap_xml)
      response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/xml"    
    
      return response
    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

So I see `app.url_map.iter_rules()` iterates through all routes. However, I would like to exclude all routes that have `@login_required` applied to them.

for example i **want**:

```
@bp.route("/")
@bp.route("/index")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

But I **don't want**:

```
@bp.route('/profile')
@login_required
def profile():
    return render_template('profile.html')
```

How can I achieve this? And are there any other useful tips for "accessing properties" of defined routes?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have that many "static" pages, for now I solved it by adding a list `include_pages` and checking the `rule.rule` against it with `and rule.rule in include_pages`, like so:

```
@bp.route('/sitemap.xml', methods=['GET'])
def sitemap():
    try:
      """Generate sitemap.xml. Makes a list of urls and date modified."""
      include_pages = [
           '/'
          ,'/index'
          ,'/faq'
          ,'/privacypolicy'
          ,'/termsandconditions'
      ]
      pages=[]
      ten_days_ago=(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)).date().isoformat()
      # static pages
      for rule in current_app.url_map.iter_rules():
          #current_app.logger.debug(rule.rule)
          if "GET" in rule.methods and len(rule.arguments)==0 and rule.rule in include_pages:
              pages.append(
                           
["http://pythonprogramming.net"+str(rule.rule),ten_days_ago]
                           )

      sitemap_xml = render_template('sitemap_template.xml', pages=pages)
      response= make_response(sitemap_xml)
      response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/xml"

      return response
    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

Still would be interested to know, if it is somehow possible to get routes excluding `@login_required`.